# Creating a new Flutter plugin: io.flutter.plugin.common module not resolved

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin

I am willing to create a Flutter plugin (to work with native code), but after opening the android native module of the Flutter project using Android Studio all the import statements for Flutter native components [are highlighted as red](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iRsoqCx2czLNjHssoFgA8-rAMbHTI-41), starting from top-level package identifier - `io`, which means that the whole module is not resolved.
Still, it is possible to launch the example project inside and it runs OK.

[Such a problem does not occur for application-typed Flutter projects](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jig4ewxDOQtIutBKPv3tJc7p_fBWaxMo) (worth mentioning that imports are not the same, but still, all the necessary imports are resolved).

Am I missing something, or it is Flutter-side bug for now? If latter, than is there a workaround for it (e.g. manually providing a library, but where is it located)?